# Customizing login with oauth2 google client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Im trying to implement in my base /login page the oauth2 login for google client

this is the security config:

```
protected void configure (final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/anonymus*").anonymous() //role anonymus
            .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()

            /*.antMatchers("/google**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/oauth2/authorization/google").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login/oauth2/code/google").permitAll()*/

            .antMatchers("/registration*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll() //resources
            .antMatchers("/addAuthors").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/addBooks").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)

            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .key("superSecretKey")
            .tokenValiditySeconds(18000) //5 ore
            .tokenRepository(tokenRepository())


            .and()
            .oauth2Login()



            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/perform_logout", "GET"))
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll();
}
```

doing this override my login html page with the default sign in of google but i want my own login page, if i change my security confing in:

```
protected void configure (final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/anonymus*").anonymous() //role anonymus
            .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()

            /*.antMatchers("/google**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/oauth2/authorization/google").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login/oauth2/code/google").permitAll()*/

            .antMatchers("/registration*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll() //resources
            .antMatchers("/addAuthors").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/addBooks").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)

            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .key("superSecretKey")
            .tokenValiditySeconds(18000) //5 ore
            .tokenRepository(tokenRepository())


            .and()
            .oauth2Login().loginPage("/login/oauth2/authorization/google")



            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/perform_logout", "GET"))
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll();
}
```

it show correctly the custom login page with a button with href set to /login/oauth2/authorization/google but when i click on it the browser remains on /login

So with the first config i have an auto generated sign in with google page that work perfectly and authenticate the user with google account but it override my basic login with email and password, in the second config i have my own login but i cant redirect to the google sign in.